# How to keep the "\n" format

Tags: c#, winforms

Creating text in notepad

`

```
 private void sSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Dat.txt", true);
            txt.Write(sTxtSurname.Text + ", " + sTxtFirstname.Text + "\n\n");
            txt.Close();
        }
```

`

displaying the text in a textbox
`

```
public void ReadFile()
        {

            TextReader reder = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\Dat.txt");
            textBox1.Text = reder.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

`

it wont diplay the "\n"

for example, i put my name and age

when displaying, it should seperate the name and age, but it doesnt

`

```
Outputs:
   Jiin Taq 19
```

`

`

```
Desired Output:
   Jiin Taq
   19
```

`

Comment: Use `Environment.NewLine` for each  `\n`

Comment: Windows in last couple of years switch return in notepad to be compatible with Linux/Core.  It basically screwed up windows applications.  What use to work, now doesn't.  You should be using txt.WriteLine (not txt.Write) and removing the \n.  This way code is compatible with the OS.

Comment: The TextBox Control use `\r\n` to generate a *physical* new line. If you add the same text to a RichTextBox, you get the *correct* result in any case, since this Control uses `\n` as new line -- Not clear what *Creating text in notepad* means; Notepad is an application, not a format

Comment: "when displaying, it should seperate the name and age, but it doesnt" --> Your posted code writes `sTxtSurname.Text` and `sTxtFirstname.Text` separated by a comma. `Age` is never referenced or written out...